# Heroku deploy Django application

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to launch my Django application with Heroku but when I execute the command "Heroku local" I get the following error .... Anyone can explain why?
Before writing this post I tried to make various changes and read up on the official website but it didn't work.

To run heroku in local I ran

```
Heroku local
```

in my main directory, with gunicorn everything was fine but apparently with heroku I'm doing something wrong.

I've also created a Procfile with the following line inside of it:

```
web: gunicorn social_site.wsgi
```

where social_site is the name of the app.

[image: The result of the error obtained]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: You don't get to pick your port on Heroku. Instead of hard-coding port 5000, use the port given to you by the `PORT` environment variable. See the linked duplicates.